# Python intersection output

Tags: python

```
def union(A,B):
    k = A
    for i in B:
        k.add(i)
    return k
def intersection(A,B):
    k = set()
    for i in A:
        if i in B:
            k.add(i)
            print(k)
    return k
A = {1,2,3}
B = {1,2,4}
assert( union(A,B)== {1,2,3,4} )
assert( intersection(A,B) == {1,2} )
```

So I am just trying to do a simple intersection function. I think I can make it work another way if I really need to but I'm worried there's something major I missing so I figured I should ask here to better understand what is going on.

It is clear to me that the intersection of the two sets should be {1,2}, however for some reason, the for function iterating 'in' A pulls out a 4 when this is clearly not in the set A!

edit: posting my whole code here because apparently posting only the segment does not give an error.

Comment: It returned `{1,2}` for me using your exact code.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. `intersection({1,2,3}, {1,2,4})` returns `{1,2}`.

Comment: When asking a question, please explain what exactly is the problem. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Not an answer (and your question is unanswerable as it stands), but I hope you're aware sets have an `intersection` method built in.

Comment: I don't understand why it returned the exact right thing for you guys...

Comment: try printing the value of `A` before `assert( intersection(A,B) == {1,2} )` statement

Comment: Well apparently printing, A right before intersection gives {1,2,3,4}, but printing it right before union gives {1,2,3}, but I see no reason why it would change the value of A in the union function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line of code 
`k=A` to 
`k = set(A)` to create a local copy of A and to not update the original set A as sets are mutable objects in python

A good read https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747

Comment: Thanks! That worked... so setting an equals on a set... updates the set??? I don't understand why...

Comment: `k = A` just makes `k` another reference to the same set the name `A` refers to.  You should read [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the `union` function. When you write `k = A`, `k` and `A` refer to the same set. So when you add elements to `k`, they are added to `A`. Then `A` is not the same when calling `intersection(A,B)`

Instead of `k = A`, write `k = A.copy()` to create a separate object.

Comment: This is very odd... since when is setting equals an excuse to update the right-hand side? Is it not like a rule that in most languages setting an equality only updates the left-hand side?

Comment: For objects like list, dict, set or custom objects, when you use the = sign, both sides refer to the same object, to avoid useless processing (copying a big object takes a lot of memory and time). Indeed most of the time this is enough. So when you want to create a copy, you have to use the copy method or use what mad_ described. But you must remember this is a costly operation.

Answer (score -1):

The intersection of A and B is easily achieved using built-in set functions.

```
>>> A = [1,2,3,'foo','bar']
>>> B = [2,4,'stack','overflow','foo']
>>> set(A) & set(B)
set([2, 'foo'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am pretty sure OP wants to write his own intersection method